# Improve output format

Tags: formatting

Could someone take a look at this output in pdf form and tell me is there a way that I could avoid so much empty space at the end of pages 1 and 3? Apologies for sending ALL the code, but it's necessary to see the final output.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, right = 1in, left = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}


\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\centering

{\scshape\LARGE University College Cork\par}

\vspace{1cm}

{\scshape\Large CE 2001: Lab Reports\par}
{\scshape\large Dr. Virkam Pakrashi\par}

\HRule

\vspace{0.4cm}

{\huge \bfseries \#1: Simply Supported Beam\par}

\vspace{0.4cm}

\HRule

\vspace{1.5cm}

{\large
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\Large\textbf{Authors:}\\
David \textsc{O'Sullivan}\\
Yuriy \textsc{Lishchynskyy}\\
John \textsc{Kearney}\\
Billy \textsc{O'Connor}\\
Eoghan \textsc{Kelleher}
\end{tabular}
\par}

\vspace{4cm}

{\large \today\par}

\vfill

\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\section{Objectives}
\begin{itemize}
\item To calculate the stiffness parameter of a beam via the load-displacement graph and subsequently calculate the Young's Modules of the beam.
\item To calculate the displacement of the beam at it's midpoint under various quarter-span loading conditions.
\item To calculate and compare the theoretical and experimental displacement along the beam under one (1 kg) quarter-span loading condition.
\end{itemize}
\section{Equipment}
A cantilever beam is placed horizontally on two supports, one fixed and the other a roller allowing the user to adjust the beam length. 
A dial gauge is used to measure the displacement along the length of the beam under various conditions of quarter-span loading.

The equipment setup is described perfectly by the following image.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{Setup}\label{tab:set}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Pic1}
\end{figure}
\section{Procedure}
\begin{itemize}
\item Take dimensions of the beam ($B$, $D$, $L$), - rectangular cross section.
\item Read initial displacement values, $w_0$, at locations $x$.
\item Apply successive and equal load masses at both quarter spans.
\item For each mass loading: \begin{itemize}
\item Measure the vertical displacement at mid-span.
\item Plot a point on the load-displacement graph (Load = $m \times g$).\end{itemize}
\item Determine the stiffness parameter, k (slope of the load-displacement graph).
\item Theoretical stiffness value; rearrange to get E. (See equation (1) below)
\item Place a unit mass, $m$, (1 kg) at each quarter span.
\item Read the values of displacement, $w_1$, at the locations, $x$ (different locations along length).
\item Calculate theoretical values of displacement, use symmetry. (See equation (2) below)
\item Plot the values of the displacement over the length of the beam for both experimental and theoretical data.


\end{itemize}
\section{Results}
\subsection{Calculating Young's Modulus}
The following is a table of quarter-span masses applied to the beam, the total mass applied and the displacement observed at the centre point of the beam (i.e. 500 mm).
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Displacement-Load table}\label{tab:t1}
\medskip
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
Quarter-Span m (kg)& Total m (kg) & Displacement (mm) \\ \toprule
0.0 & 0.0 & 15.22 \\ 
0.1 & 0.2 &  14.9 \\ 
0.2 & 0.4 & 14.58 \\ 
0.3 & 0.6 & 14.23 \\ 
0.4 & 0.8 & 13.9  \\ 
0.5 & 1.0 & ?     \\ 
0.6 & 1.2 & 13.25 \\ 
0.7 & 1.4 & 12.91 \\ 
0.8 & 1.6 & 12.58 \\ 
0.9 & 1.8 & 12.23 \\ \toprule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
The values of mass in both the first and second column will be multiplied by the acceleration due to gravity ($g$) in order to convert them to the \textit{Weight} applied to the beam. The values for displacement in the third column are uncalibrated and therefore must be calibrated in order to plot the total load vs. displacement graph. These values must be calibrated against the value of displacement for zero loading conditions (row 1, column 3 in table above). Thus all subsequent values of displacement, for the various loads, will be calibrated against (i.e. subtracted from) 15.22 mm. \textbf{Note: The displacement for the quarter-span mass of 0.5 kg is not shown and will be addressed in the Discussion section}. The following graph of total load (column two times $g$) vs. displacement is then obtained.\vspace{-10pt}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{Load vs. Displacement}\label{tab:g1}
\vspace{-15pt}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Graph1}
\end{figure}

The slope of the trendline obtained from the above graph is 5.91 \si{N.mm^{-1}}. This value refers to the stiffness paramter, $k$, in the equation:\\ \begin{equation}
\boxed{k \approx \frac{384EI}{11L^3}}
\end{equation}\\
Where $E$ is the Young's Modulus of the beam material, $I$ is the second moment of area of the beam and $L$ is the length of the beam. Now knowing $k$, the above equation can be rearranged and $E$ can be calculated. The beam parameters are as follows:
\begin{itemize}
\item Length (mm) = 1000
\item Width (mm) = 24
\item Height (mm) = 6
\item I (\si{mm^4}) = $432$
\end{itemize}
Rearranging equation (1) to find $E$ and subbing in for the above values and $k$ gives rise to:$$E = \frac{(11)(1000^3)(5.91)}{(384)(432} = 391  \si{GPa}$$
\subsection{Four Point Bending:}
The next section of the experiment involved applying 1 kg masses to each quarter span of the beam and then measuring the values of displacement at each position across the beam's length.
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Displacements}\label{tab:t2}

\begin{tabular}{cccccc}\bottomrule
Station & $w_0$ (mm) & $w_1$ (mm) & Calibrated $w_0$ & Calibrated $w_1$ & $w_1 - w_0$ \\ \toprule
0 & 16.86 & 16.86 & 0.04 & 0.04 & 0.00  \\ 
1 & 16.71 & 15.76 & 0.19 & 1.14 & 0.95  \\
2 & 16.38 & 14.35 & 0.52 & 2.55 & 2.03 \\ 
3 & 15.98 & 13.50 & 0.92 & 3.4  & 2.48 \\ 
4 & 15.42 & 12.61 & 1.48 & 4.29 & 2.81 \\ 
5 & 15.22 & 12.27 & 1.68 & 4.63 & 2.95  \\ 
6 & 15.62 & 12.74 & 1.28 & 4.16 & 2.88 \\ 
7 & 16.37 & 13.89 & 0.53 & 3.01 & 2.48 \\ 
8 & 16.83 & 14.99 & 0.07 & 1.91 & 1.84  \\ 
9 & 16.93 & 15.96 & -0.03 & 0.94 & 0.97 \\ 
10 & 16.94 & 16.94 & -0.04 & -0.04 & 0.00 \\ \toprule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
The values of $w_0$ and $w_1$ are calibrated against the average initial displacement at the supports (where no deformation occurs). This is calculated to be 16.90 mm. The theoretical displacement is defined by the following piecewise function:
\begin{equation}
\boxed{w_{Theory} =
\begin{cases}
\frac{Px}{6EI}(3aL - 3a^2 - x^2), &0\leq x\leq a \\
\frac{Pa}{6EI}(3Lx - 3x^2 - a^2), & a\leq x\leq L - a
\end{cases}}
\end{equation}

Using equations (2) one can find all the displacements along the length of the beam. For the beam used in the experiment, $a = \frac{1}{4}L = 250$ mm. $P$ is the load applied at both quarter-spans and in this case it was a constant 1 kg mass, i.e. a 9.8 N downward weight. 

The following table may then be constructed. \textbf{Note:The values of $w_T$ are implicitly calibrated.}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Theoretical Displacement}\label{tab:t3}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
Range & Location (mm) & $w_T$ (mm) \\ \hline
& 0 & 0.00 \\ 
$0\leq x\leq a$ &100 & 0.53 \\ 
&200 & 1.00 \\ \hline
& 300 & 1.37 \\ 
&400 & 1.58 \\ 
$a\leq x\leq L-a$&500 & 1.66     \\ 
&600 & 1.58 \\ 
&700 & 1.37 \\ \hline
 & 800 & 1.00 \\ 
$L-A\leq x\leq L$&900 & 0.53 \\ 
&1000 & 0.00 \\ \toprule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
The following graph plots the $w_T$ and $w_E$ ($w_1 - w_0$) against the various beam positions.\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{Graph of $w_T$ and $w_E$.}\label{tab:g2}\vspace{-20pt}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{G4}
\end{figure}\vspace{-20pt}
The various graphs and trends will be discussed in the Discussion section of this report.
\section{Discussion}
Relevant measurements were kept in mm as this was the standard unit on the dial gauge that monitored deflection. This sustained a uniformity across the experiment and report.
\subsection{Young's Modulus}
The ends of the beams had a displacement of 16.86 mm and 16.94 mm respectively. This is a difference of 0.08 mm. This was not expected seeing as the deflection at both endpoints should have been 0 mm. This discrepancy is most likely due to residual stresses left in the beam after repeated loading. This was easily dealt with in the calculations by averaging the two values to give a value against which the other readings could be calibrated.

There were no 0.5 kg masses available to use for this section of the experiment and thus there is a vacant data point in figure 2 above. The value of displacement for the 0.5 kg quarter-span loading condition (9.8 N total) can be simply read from the graph via extrapolation. This yields a value of approximately 1.65 mm. Or, alternatively the value of 9.81 N could've been subbed into the equation of the line for the Load-Displacement graph and thus $x$ could've been solved for. 

\subsection{Four Point Bending}
Max displacement always occured at the midpoint of the beam, regardless of the fact that the point masses were placed at each quarter-span and not the midpoint, this can be proven by differentiating equation (2), on the latter interval, with respect to x and letting the derivative equal to 0. \begin{equation}
\boxed{\frac{dw_T}{dx} = \frac{Pa}{6EI}(3L - 6x)}
\end{equation}
Letting this equation equal to 0, it can be found that $x = \frac{L}{2}$ when $w_T$ is at a maximum. 

It was first observed that the beam was not at a constant displacement across it's length, i.e. the calibrated values of $w_0$ increased as one moved from the beam support to it's midpoint. This initial displacement of the beam is due to it's self weight.

The difference in the values of $w_T$ and $w_E$ is due to the beams self weight and the fact that it is not factored into the calculation of $w_T$ whilst it is included in the $w_E$ term, thus there is a difference in the graphs of $w_E$ and $w_T$ figure 3. The difference in $w_E$ and $w_T$ will therefore be approximately equal to the deformation caused by the self weight of the beam.

A clear symmetry was noted in the displacement across the length of the beam for both self-weight and point-mass loaded conditions. This symmetry took the form of a linear change in deflection approaching the midpoint from the right and left hand side. This was as the loads were symmetrically placed about the midpoint.


\section{Conclusion}
\begin{itemize}
\item The value of $E$ was found to be 391 GPa, which is extremely large. From this value, one could conclude the beam to be made of    Tungsten. This a wild guess though seeing as the value of $E$ would decrease greatly upon increasing the dimensions of the beam (see rearranged equation (1)). Thus, while it is possible that the beam material is Tungsten, it could really be a number of other materials. 
\item There were very few errors/unexpected values found in the experiment as most values showed expected trends.
\item A linear relationship was found between the applied load and the induced displacement at the midpoint of the beam.
\item It was proven that the maximum displacement in a simply supported beam occurs at the midpoint.
\end{itemize}





\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It's compiling for me. Just realising that there are images involved, so unless you have those pages in your latex folder, it won't compile. Any way around this as the images are fairly central to the question?

Comment: You could use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`, the `demo` option replaces the images with black rectangles. Or you could use the images from the `mwe` package, which are called `example-image`, `example-image-a`, `example-image-b` and `example-image-c` (and a couple more, that I cannot remember now). Anyone who has that package installed will have those images in the TeX tree, so they are directly available.

Comment: You can add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, rather than all the document.

Comment: I would guess the problem is `[H]`, when figures and tables can't float, you can get underfull pages.

Comment: Which parameter should I choose instead of [H]??

Comment: I'll repost the code in a little bit.

Comment: None, or perhaps `[bhtp]` to allow for all positions. Or a subset of those (`b` is bottom, `t` is top, `h` is here, `p` is page). See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017) for the 'full story' about float positioning.

Answer (score 3):

Not having access to the image files you use and hence not being able to re-create your document exactly, it's not possible to give definitive answers to your questions.

Some suggestions, which partly echo the ones already made in the earlier comments:

- Don't use the `[H]` float placement specifier. Instead, try `[htb!]`.
- Check whether some of the figures contain a lot of whitespace around the edges. If so, figure out how to trim off the unneeded whitespace. This should make for a more compact look.
- Issue the directive `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.

Some further comments, which pertain mainly to programming and coding efficiency and to the best use of some of macros you employ:

- You seem to hard-code many cross-references to floats and equations, even though these objects are given `\label`s. You'll find that using the `\ref` command when cross-referencing these objects will save you a lot of time almost from the start.
- Similarly, when referring to quantities and their units, don't write things such as

  ```
  5.91 \si{N.mm^{-1}}
  ```

  Instead, write

  ```
  \SI{5.91}{\newton\per\milli\meter}
  ```

  If nothing else, using the `\SI` macro will avoid encountering undesirable line breaks between the quantities and units.
- Don't use `$$` in a LaTeX document. Instead, use `\[` and `\]` to delimit an unnumbered displayed equation. See the posting [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for more information on this subject.

Last and not least, I would counsel against mis-spelling the instructor's given name ("Virkam"?!) on the title page.